# Show error message after reactive form submission

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

On an Angular 8 Reactive form I have the following:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input id="name" type="text" formControlName="name">
  <span class="error" *ngIf="form.get('name').invalid && (form.get('name').dirty || form.get('name').touched)">
    Name error
  </span>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="submitting">Send</button>
</form>
```

And the onSubmit is:

```
onSubmit() {

  this.submitting = true;

  if (this.form.valid) {
    // Submit form
  }

  this.submitting = false;

}
```

I am trying to configure the form as follows:

1. Error messages are invisible when page loads;
2. Error message for a field shows if the user types something invalid in the field;
3. Error message shows if the form is submitted and there is an error on that field.

   I would like the form to be submitted even if it is invalid.

The problem I have is:

```
When the form is submitted, without touching the Name field, the error does not show after submission.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option1:

You can add a `isSubmitted` bool variable to indicate whether or not the submit button was pressed by the user and set its value to true inside the `onSubmit()`:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.isSubmitted = true;

    //rest of you code
}
```

and set the `ngIf` to this:

```
<span *ngIf="(form.get('name').invalid && form.get('name').touched) || 
             (form.get('name').untouched && isSubmitted)">
    Not Valid
</span>
```

> 1. Error messages are invisible when page loads;

The first line `form.get('name').invalid && form.get('name').touched` responsible.

> 2. Error message for a field shows if the user types something invalid in
>      the field;

Angular framework does this by default.

> 3. Error message shows if the form is submitted and there is an error on that field.

The second line `form.get('name').untouched && isSubmitted`

### Option2

As in this great [article](https://loiane.com/2017/08/angular-reactive-forms-trigger-validation-on-submit/), on submitting you can iterate all of the controllers and set them as touched with:

```
Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(field => {
    const control = this.form.get(field);
    control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
});
```

So you could leave the markup a bit cleaner:

```
<span *ngIf="form.get('name').invalid && form.get('name').touched">
    Not Valid
</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me in Angular 13. [Working Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-validation-on-submit). [Code on Github](https://github.com/aniket-kale/angular-reactive-form-validation-on-submit)

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input id="name" type="text" formControlName="name" />
  <div
    *ngIf="
      form.get('name')?.invalid &&
      (form.get('name')?.dirty || form.get('name')?.touched)
    "
    class="alert alert-danger"
  >
    <div *ngIf="form.get('name')?.errors?.['required']">Field is required.</div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Use `markAllAsTouched` to show validation

```js
onSubmit() {
  this.form.markAllAsTouched();
  if (this.form.valid) {
    console.log('Form is valid');
  } else {
    console.log('Form is not valid');
  }
}
```